# If we were to know everything about the universe right after the Big Bang, can we predict me eating toast today?

Tags: determinism

It is implied, per QM, that the behavior of subatomic particles cannot be precisely predicted. However, these indeterministic effects do have defined probabilities. By the law of large numbers, they can “average” out and result in approximately deterministic laws.

For this reason, I presume, we can predict with pinpoint accuracy whether or not atleast some kinds of events will happen in the macro scale even if we can’t know their minute details on a subatomic level.

The question then is how fine or loose grained of an event is predictable given all knowledge about antecedent conditions. And how antecedent must these conditions be?

Suppose I woke up today at 9 AM and ate toast for breakfast. If I were to know everything that could be possibly known about the configuration of the universe right after the Big Bang, is this event predictable? Can one say, given that knowledge, with assuredness whether or not this will happen?

Comment: I like the way you put the question, which to me highlights the absurdity of the determinist claim.

Comment: Not an expert, but it would seem to me, that over such a long time there would be 'threshold' influences of quantum/micro events which might tip the scales at macro level, and that over time, these would build into significant diversions from pure determinism; the greater the time, the greater the divergence. Does this make sense? EG: Your eating toast _may_ have been predictable, but then again, you existence at all may not have been predictable, let alone you eating toast.

Comment: It's absurd to have such simplified causal implication for your eating toast today *seemingly* actually happened, the Solomon's lemegaton lies in in *reality* nothing can be said to be actually actualized by some 1-d sequence of a super long causal chain in this Saha world, there're many *dynamically* entangled worlds where either you are not born yet or eating eggs today instead or what come it may, the ability to predict either one of them in some sense spookily depends on your degree of belief as *presentiment* of the said event while remembering your past observed consistent histories...

Comment: I could have predicted you eating toast without knowing anything about the beginning of the universe.

Answer (score 2):

No event is predictable from the conditions right after the Big Bang. As far as we can extrapolate, the conditions were extremely simple: There was a singularity with no other properties than its existence. Total information content (complexity) of the Universe was one bit.

All subsequent evolution, the increase in universal complexity and entropy are the results of unpredictable probabilistic events.

The Universe is not deterministic, absolute accuracy is not a thing of reality.

Comment: Even if the singularity seems to be extremely small just after the Big Bang, it contained a gigantic matter (mass + energy), it was extremly hot and heavy. By consequence, the information that this singularity contained can not be as small as one bit but very high.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the concept of singularity. The whole universe was just one particle with no form.

Comment: You've come a long way, baryons.

Answer (score 2):

No. We have no theory yet into which to input the data. Even if we imagine a fictional universe without gravity so that we can apply QM to every problem, still no. QM needs somewhere outside of the phenomenon described by the wavefunction to put the physicist, so it can't take whole universes as inputs.

If we take the fictional no-gravity Milky Way ten billion years ago, and we build a really big box with a really high heat capacity around it, and we put a physicist outside of it, and we let that physicist ask his wizard friend for the exact wavefunction of the whole system inside of the box, then the physicist can calculate the probability that a measurement at a certain time ten billion years later in a certain place inside the still-sealed box will return an instance of you eating toast. It will be a vanishingly small probability.

I should note that the physicist may need his wizard friend to do the computation by magic, or to magically summon a computer much bigger than a galaxy in which to run the simulation. Normally simulation works because of simplifying assumptions, but if we magically have the wavefunction of the whole macroscopic system, we have no simplifying assumptions.

Comment: It takes a universe to simulate a universe.

Answer (score -1):

The question of determinism boils down to: could something else have happened? If there exists a possible world in which you didn't eat toast, how would this world have come to be? If you want to use QM, you will need to answer at which point did a particle bounce to the right and produce the current reality, when it could also have bounced left to produce an alternate reality?

As you say, there are so incredibly many particles that the odds of a *meaningful* change being effected by QM dice falling the other way is exceptionally low. The law of large numbers effectively means that nothing else could have happened. Yes, you were destined to eat toast.

Obviously, none of this is particularly useful; it is well beyond any supercomputer to know every state and every physics rule.

Comment: The discovery of chaos being intrinsic to even some very simple math relationships is a refuting test case to your claims about the “Law of large numbers”.  SOME of physics is driven by the law of large numbers and is effectively reductionist.  Some of physics is chaotic and amplifies quantum indeterminacy.  Our universe is therefore indeterminist, and no thinking man was not determined to eat toast.

Comment: @Dcleve first of all, something being chaotic only means that it is *unpredictable*, not that it is *non-deterministic*. Random Number Generation is chaotic, yet perfectly determined by a simple math formula. Second, if you are going to make the claim that the butterfly effect influences the formation of stars and galaxies, you will need to provide some evidence for that. I have no idea what the  Lyapunov exponent would be for the universe, do you?

Comment: Your second question is explicitly answered by cosmologists.  Their assumed mechanism for galaxy formation IS local density fluctuations at the very beginning of Inflation.  This principle that quantum phenomena leverage up is easily established by considering a triple pendulum and the effect of the HUP on the ability to determine its location 10 years later.  Note all solid objects oscillate/vibrate, generally with more modes than a triple pendulum.  All even macro level interactions have an HUP leveraged up uncertainty.

Comment: @Dcleve again, the inability to detemine a pendulum's trajectory is merely a sign of unpredictibility, not a proof of non-determinism. You shouldn't conflate these terms. Neither does the HUP entail that either speed or location are *random* within a certain range, it only asserts that we cannot know both with absolute certainty at the same time. Quite frankly I think the idea that quantum effects would 'leverage up' rather than cancel each other out is ludicrous. There are 10^27 particles in a normal sized triple pendulum. QM is perfectly negligable at that scale.

Comment: Jumboman, the math by which quantum uncertainty leverages up to macro scales is explicit in Chaos theory. Your disbelief in it based on “wish it weren’t so” is a fallacy. And no, the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is not some bizarre and inexplicable limit on “what we know” but instead is s limit on what can be real. The efforts to try to recast it as “just” a limit on us, not on the universe, conflict with the physics of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Dcleve I can only repeat the case of RNG. The numbers generated by the algorithm are chaotic and unpredictable. Small changes in the initial seed leverage up, as chaos theory indeed predicts. Now, the nanotransistors inside my computer are made up of particles that are subject to QM. However, the randomness in RNG does not stem from QM, but from the algorithm. If QM had an effect on RNG, starting from *the same seed* would produce different results in the long term. However, it does not. This is because the transistors are large enough that the chance of a bit flipping due to QM is <<<<low.

Comment: @Dcleve Perhaps I should have been more clear when I used the word *I think*. I meant that it's completely *unproven* and wildly unrealistic that there are systems which are só chaotic, só sensitive to initial conditions, with súch a high Lyapunov exponent, that a 3-pound, 10^27 particles triple pendulum would show a *measurable* deviation in it's trajectory due to a probabilistic change in a single atom, within a timeframe that is relevant to humans (say, a lifetime), and probably even a million years.

Comment: Jumboman -- I provided you an example where QM uncertainty leverages up.   The math is explicit and undeniable. Your then looking for special cases where the leveraging is small, is continuing to operate under confirmation bias.  There are of course other "special cases" where HUP will produce measurable uncertainty in days, or less, satisfying the refutation needed to disprove your claim.  If you want to say that HUP NEVER will matter to humans, a case of pancreatic cancer serves as a very effective, tho not calculable refutation.

Comment: @Dcleve which example would that be? You've not mentioned a single actual source for your claims. I'd be happy to look at an example where *specifically* the HUP/QM is responsible for the uncertainty of a normal-sized object's movement, rather than just chaos theory in general. If a paper with the title "we could not predict the trajectory of this triple pendulum *because of quantum effects*" exists I'll gladly concede. Dito for "quantum mechanics causes cancer": I've looked for sources that back that up, but cannot find any. That's a statement that desperately needs a source.

Comment: Jumboman -- I have explicitly pointed you to the triple pendulum equations, and as those scale, they can readily be scaled down to a pendulum size that will have measurable and causal effects due to HUP within a human lifetime.  Why deny this?  Are you also denying that radiation causes cancer????  Loads of articles, over nearly a hundred years, document this.

Comment: @Dcleve I have googled "quantum triple pendulum equations" and found nothing which I think you mean, so clearly you were not 'explicit'. 
As for radiation, of course we know how bundles of energy can break DNA chains or facilitate certain harmful chemical reactions. What you have not provided any source or explanation for is how this is impacted by probabilistic density functions or the HUP. particle hits particle, particle changes, people get cancer: simple cause and effect. What is indeterministic about that?

Comment: Jumboman -- the vector and timing of all radiation is indeterminate per HUP.  Whether such a radiation vector intercepts the location of a DNA or RNA strand, such that it causes a cancerous molecular change, is therefore indeterministic.

Comment: All chemical interaction induced cancers also are driven by HUP uncertainties.  Complex organic molecules all have more complicated modal behaviors than a triple pendulum, and their masses are small enough that HUP uncertainties affect the contact behaviors that determine what chemical interactions take place between two specific complex organic molecules.  It is not just radiation-induced cancers that are indeterministic, the chemical ones are as well.

Comment: @Dcleve the *odds* of getting cancer from a single gamma ray is uncountably small, as we are bombarded with all sorts of radiation every second. Cancer due to radiation happens after you have been exposed to a very large number of such particles. Usually, if particle nr. 1253523 didn't cause cancer because of the HUP, particle nr. 6436432 would have. This is what I mean by the law of large numbers. It's not that one unlucky density collapse that caused cancer, it's the entire cube of uranium. The same goes for chemical reactions. of course they're governed by QM, but to conclude that ...

Comment: @Dcleve people who did not get cancer are "quantum-lucky" because somehow ALL of their atoms/molecules miraculously dodged a cancer-producing collision with another particle, I'm sure you'll agree is wrong. A single collision *happens or does not happen* because of QM, but it was *guaranteed to happen* because there were so many of those particles. I guess this is both an example of leveraging up AND large numbers. I'm not sure we'll ever agree.

Comment: Jumboman -- that someone gets pancreatic cancer from either an HUP driven radiation event or HUP driven chemical reaction is -- explicitly NOT deterministic.  You have just agreed with that, by admitting that it is "luck", yet are trying to refuse to accept the inevitable conclusion about our world being macro-level not deterministic.

Comment: @Dcleve This is the last time I'll attempt to bridge the gap. If I flip a single coin, the outcome is determined by chance, 50-50. So yes, if I flip two trillion coins, *technically* you'd be correct to say that the outcome is also determined by chance - indeterministically. Maybe the number of heads is 10^12+532. Or 10^12 + 216. You can validly claim indeterminism on that. The question was: does it matter? Does the micro-indeterminism leverage up to *meaningful* levels? For all *practical intents and purposes*, we can *predict with certainty* that roughly a trillion coins will land on heads.

Comment: @Dcleve It is exactly for that reason that micro-indeterminism does not automatically lead to *meaningful* macro-indeterminism. It's not an inevitable conclusion at all. In fact, this is the whole basis for entropy. In theory, energy can flow from cold object to a hot object. There's a chance for that to happen. But because there are so many molecules in an object, that chance becomes neglible, and we are guaranteed that energy flows from hot to cold. Probabilities effectively *become* expected values when taken to their limit. Chance becomes number. Indeterminism becomes determinism.

Comment: @Dcleve when you say that micro-indeterminism always leads to macro-indeterminism, you are effectively saying that when you mix a liter of chloride and a liter of turpentine, there is a *chance* that a reaction will occur, and a *chance* that the HUP leads to no reaction at all. You'd be simultaneously right (there is a 'chance' that there will be no reaction) and wrong (the chance is 0.00000%). You *know* it's going to react and you *know* the solution that you will end up with. So where is the indeterminism?

Comment: see also: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/hnj5x/does_quantum_indeterminacy_affect_macroscopic/
"Well, if everything is ultimately quantum-mechanical and quantum mechanics is ultimately non-deterministic (which is a matter of interpretation, although most believe it is), then it follows that macroscopic events are in-principle non-deterministic.

But quantum events are so minute from the macroscopic point of view, it's not very significant."

Comment: see also: https://www.quora.com/To-what-extent-does-quantum-indeterminacy-complicate-attempts-to-make-claims-about-the-universes-past-based-on-current-conditions "Saying that the world is nondeterministic, I think, misses the point altogether." and "Of course we know full well that these "classical" components are, in reality, quantum systems themselves, albeit ones with a very large number of degrees of freedom; and their states are not true eigenstates, just indistinguishable from such, due to the *law of averages* over those many degrees of freedom. " (emphasis mine)